# How can I get code coverage for a constructor method in a StandardSet controller?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I am struggling hard to get code coverage for following constructor method with some URL method usage. Basically the filter name I am trying to fetch is the list view ID (also need some insights to how to dynamically fetch list view id in test class for coverage)

Here is my constructor method:

```
public constructormethod(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    this.setCon = controller;
    objectName = setCon.getRecord().getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

    sUrl = Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl();


    if(sUrl.contains('filterName')){  **// On running test class is failing with null exception at this line** 
        filterId = sUrl.substringAfter('%3FfilterName%3D').left(18);
}
}
```

test class I did so far:

```
 @isTest
 public class test_constructormethod{ 
      List<Contact>  testContacts = tdp.listContacts();
      /** test contacts add logic

      **/
      insert testContacts;

     PageReference pageRef = Page.YOUR_VF_PAGE; 
     ApexPages.StandardSetController stdctrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(testContacts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get current page information through `ApexPages.currentPage()`, but you are not setting/specifying the page itself.

Try to set it before calling the controller using this:

```
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.YOUR_VF_PAGE);
```